# How does python work for the object operation?

Tags: python

I find an interstion phenomenon, but I can not figure it out.
when I input this:

```
a=np.array([1,4,2,3,4,4])
c=a[1:4]
c=c-1
```

the output is
c>>[3,1,3],a>>[1,4,2,4,4,4]

however, when I input this code

```
a=np.array([1,4,2,4,4,4])
c=a[1:4]
c[c==4]=c[c==4]-1
```

the output is
c>>[3,1,3],a>>[1,3,1,3,4,4]

why the "a" changes at the second time while keep tha same at the first time?

Answer (score 2):

```
c = c-1
```

creates a new array from `c-1` and assigns that to `c`. It doesn't modify the original array.

```
c[c==4] = c[c==4]-1
```

is assigning to the selected elements of `c`, which modifies the array in place.

And since `c` is a view into `a`, it also modifies `a` at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Pointer shennanigans, basically.

For the first case:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.zeros((5,))
b = a[1:4]
b = b + 1

print(f'a = {a}')
print(f'b = {b}')

pointer_a, _ = a[1:4].__array_interface__['data']
pointer_b, _ = b.__array_interface__['data']

a_is_b = pointer_a == pointer_b
print('a is b') if a_is_b else print('a is not b')
```

This should print

```
a = [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
b = [1. 1. 1.]
a is not b
```

For the second case:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.zeros((5,))
b = a[1:4]
b[b==0] = b[b==0] + 1

print(f'a = {a}')
print(f'b = {b}')

pointer_a, _ = a[1:4].__array_interface__['data']
pointer_b, _ = b.__array_interface__['data']

a_is_b = pointer_a == pointer_b
print('a is b') if a_is_b else print('a is not b')
```

This should print

```
a = [0. 1. 1. 1. 0.]
b = [1. 1. 1.]
a is b
```

Basically, `b` and `a[1:4]` originally point to the same memory address. Depending on how you attempt to modify `b` (*i.e.*, which syntax you use), you will either alter the values at the original physical memory location, or you will make a copy of the array at a new physical location in memory.

`b = b + 1` means "copy the values at `a[1:4]` to a new location and add `1`, then assign the variable `b` to this location".

`b[b==0] = b[b==0] + 1` means "look at the values in `a[1:4]` where `a[1:4]` is `0` and add `1` to these values".

If you had written `b = b[b==0] + 1` you would have gotten the same result as in the case where `b = b + 1`.